# How to get inner tr tag using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab documentnumber attribute from the tr tags inside tbody, and save it in an array.

Below is the html , I am working on

```
<tbody class="line-item-grid-body">
    <tr data-group-sequence-number-field-index="" data-sequence-number-field-index="1" documentnumber="80" documentid="4133604" parent="80" class="line-item parent-line-item line-item-show reorderable-row  droppable-element">
        <td> 
                 <table>
                   <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
                   </tbody>
                 </table>
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr data-group-sequence-number-field-index="" data-sequence-number-field-index="1" documentnumber="80" documentid="4133604" parent="80" class="line-item parent-line-item line-item-show reorderable-row  droppable-element">
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is what I did, which is not working. If I don't specify particular class then system also grabs inner tr tags, which I don't want

```
var docs = jQuery("#line-item-grid").find('tbody').find("tr[class='line-item parent-line-item line-item-show reorderable-row  droppable-element']");

for (i=1;i<=docs.length;i++)
{
var tempValue = jQuery(docs[i]).attr('documentnumber');
alert(tempValue);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `tr[@class=...` instead. The `@` indicates you want to match on an attribute.

Comment: Why are there table *rows* inside your table *cells*, why do you have two identical unclosed rows...?

Comment: And why are you using an attribute selector for class anyways, it should look like `tr.line-item.parent-line-item.line-item-show.reorderable-row.droppable-element`

Comment: HTML? Last time I saw something similar is from MS Word several years ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several ways you could go about this. I would do the following....

```
var docs = $('.line-item-grid-body>tr');
```

Docpage: [Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Another option:

```
var docs = $('.line-item-grid-body').children('tr');
```

Bookmark and frequent this page ... [Selectors - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: thanks dude for your timely response...worked like a charm..appreciate that !!

Answer (score 2):

try this as your selector

```
  $('tbody > tr','#line-item-grid');
```

Comment: That worked but I am getting documentnumber of first <tr> tag, then undefined, and then documentnumber of last <tr> tag. Anything else I am missing?

Comment: Try changing your for loop to

     `docs.each(function(i,item){ alert($(item).attr('documentnumber);});`

Also bear in mind the comments on your post about unclosed tags

Comment: Same result, one alert comes with undefined value and next with correct value. if I have five tr tags, there will be 10 alerts with one undefined and next correct value. I have unclosed tags in actual html, just updated my question. Is there a way, i can skip one each time

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i didn't test this (so check for typos), but off top of my head, i'd try something like this:

```
jQuery(".line-item-grid tbody > tr").each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('documentnumber');
});
```

You can define selectors one after another, pretty much same as in CSS.
Also check child selector (http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for selecting direct child elements.

Hope it helps